# Unable to build a new react-native project on xCode 14

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

facing a following issue with `react-native-area-view-context` package only in xCode app works fine while runing from terminal,[image]

I tried re-installing package, clearing node_modules, npm cache and re installing pod files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is more related to react-native new architecture, and I'm finally able to fix it by updated all the packages to their latest versions.

And after that I installed the pod using

`bundle install && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install`